# Debugging techniques for robot_localization?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've managed to put together a typical setup for robot_localization using wheel encoders, IMU and GPS, as described in the documentation and in many answers here. It works more or less reasonably well. But sometimes it doesn't. My question would be about debugging techniques for the case when it doesn't. I'm wondering how you guys do this tuning / debugging thing? There are literally hundreds of messages generated when the system is running, most of them with loads of numbers in them. Are there any magic tools, clever tricks, methods, best practices, etc. to find out what's going wrong when something is going wrong? I use `rviz` and `rostopic`. Are these really the only weapons I have?

I hope this question is not too generic for this forum. But I would be really interested to hear how people with more experience deal with this phase of development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356975/debugging-techniques-for-robot_localization-?/) by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rviz`, [`plotjuggler`](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler) and `rosbag` are your friends. Record a bag file using `rosbag` of an occasion when it doesn't work well, then replay that through `rviz` and `plotjuggler`, looking at what the various different sensors and calculated values are doing.

https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on 2020-07-13**:
`plotjuggler` looks awesome. Thank you.